# Why can you not factor out the LCM variable in the code for conditional statement?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

Having trouble understanding Boolean expression for factoring out 0.

```
x,y=24,36

LCM=1

counting=True

while counting:
    if (LCM%x and LCM%y) == 0:
        print('The LCM is {}'.format(LCM))
        break
    
    LCM+=1
```

**LCM evaluates to 24, which is false**

But this code gives the correct LCM:

```
x,y=24,36

LCM=1

counting=True

while counting:
    if LCM%x==0 and LCM%y == 0:
        print('The LCM is {}'.format(LCM))
        break
    
    LCM+=1
```

**LCM is 72, this is correct**

Now why can 0 not be factored out? Generally if I type something like 2 and 3 == 0, the expression evaluates to false, but shouldn't syntax work similarly in the example above. So I getting confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, `0 == False` evaluates to `True`. So `(LCM%x and LCM%y) == 0` evaluates to `True` when the condition `(LCM%x and LCM%y)` is `False`. When does that happen? Whenever **either** of the values `LCM%x` or `LCM%y` is zero.

In your second example, you have `LCM%x==0 and LCM%y == 0` which evaluates to `True` only if **both** `LCM%x` and `LCM%y` are zero.

Comment: A concise answer that got the point across.

Answer (score 1):

Because here' it's happening like a binary operation and not as a logical check statement

(0 and 1) = 0 when LCM = 24

```
if (LCM%x and LCM%y) == 0:
```

This is happening because the values are 0 and  1 here(Python mistook it for a binary operation but you wanted something else).

If it is like (24 and 36) then it would return the max of two! So be careful when you give conditions to Python/any language!

But here it is the value check like is LCM divisible by x like

```
if LCM%x==0 and LCM%y == 0:
```

is 24%24 == 0? and is 36%24 ==0 ?

PS : Use the default Python IDLE, it will give you a clearer view in such simple operations!
[image]

Comment: Thanks it clarified sufficiently.